# expo app access to location, but never use

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, expo

I have on google play console, a warning because I have this :

```
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

so I have to explain why my app use location,

but on my application, I never use the location..

any idea to find where my app use location?

Comment: Are you sure you are not asking location permission in the manifest?. Edit: maybe you use some library that need it maybe?

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade your expo to 39 simply run `expo upgrade`
2. Add this on android object config `"permissions": []`
3. run `expo build:android -t apk` again